# Who field is not updated c# domino calendar creation

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, interop-domino

I was trying to create calendar using c# interop.domino.dll function call , the calendar was created successfully but the WHO field is not updated.

```
     static void CreateMeeting(NotesDatabase userDatabase)
{
    if (!userDatabase.IsOpen)
    {
        userDatabase.Open();
    }
    NotesDocument LNDocument = userDatabase.CreateDocument();
    System.DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 25, 6, 0, 0);
    System.DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2019, 12, 25, 6, 3, 0);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Appointment");
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("AppointmentType", "Meeting");
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", "Dec 25 - Chirstmas Celebration");
    //Set Confidential Level (Public=1 or Private=0) 
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("$PublicAccess", "1");

    //Add Start&End Time of your event
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("CALENDARDATETIME", StartDate);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("StartDateTime", StartDate);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("EndDateTime", EndDate);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("StartDate", StartDate);
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Location", "Meeting Hall");
    //Add From and To 
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Chair", "test/test@test");
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("From", "test@DS.test.com");
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Required", "test1/test1");
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("EnterSendTo", "test1@DS.test.com");
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("SendTo", "test1@DS.test.com");
    //Infos in The Body
    LNDocument.ReplaceItemValue("Body", "Chirtsmas DAY ...");



    LNDocument.ComputeWithForm(true, false);
    LNDocument.Save(true, false, false);
}
```

What is the mistake i am doing with the creation here ?

Comment: Please read [calendaring & scheduling schema](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/uafiles.nsf/docs/WPNotesCSSchema/$File/csschema.pdf) to find out the missing items... AppointmentType for example should be „3“ (Text, not number) and not „Meeting“... and: what do you mean by „who“? The chair or the participants?

Comment: Who appears in view/folder column headings for email, so I'm guessing that's what he's looking for in an emailed invitation. Althoug the code doesn't email this invitation, it just saves it, it does set the Form to "Appointment" and a quick glance at the formula for the Who column shows that it should be based on the Chair item -- at least in the version of the mail template that I'm looking at.

Comment: @TorstenLink participants are not updating.

Comment: Then set the right fields regarding to the link. And: you need to create a notice document so send, otherwise the participants won‘t get an invitation